# Change in Firebase billing shuts down whole Google Cloud cluster

Tags: firebase, google-compute-engine

Some time ago, I upgraded my Firebase plan to "Blaze - Pay as you go". Some weeks later, I downgraded to the free plan again. What I did not know was, this also downgraded payment on my Google Compute Engine account. As a consequence, our whole production infrastructure was shut down because by some miracle it had now means of payment anymore. It took us quite some time to get it up and running again.

Can anyone explain to me, how this can happen?

Comment: Please [reach out to Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/account-services/) for personal help.

Comment: We did have the exact same thing.. It's crazy!